# How to obtain proxy settings from IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, proxy

I'm in need of finding the proxy settings in IE in order to set up RCUrl. The settings cannot be displayed in IE (the hospital administrators have "greyed" out the entire box). I understand that there is a function available to reveal the proxy settings for IE (WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser). Since I only know R (statistics) where this function is not available-what is the easiest way to get the output from this function? Can it be called in excel?

//M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of native C++ calls that are used to retrieve this data, but if you cannot call arbitrary functions, then you're out of luck. If you can read the registry, you can read *most* of the proxy information. See HKLM and HKCU under \Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ the keys ProxyEnable, ProxyServer and ProxyOverride.

Answer (score 2):

Here's different ways to do it.  From R, use system2 to shell out to get this information.

### From PowerShell:

```
param ($reqUrl)

$source = @"
public class WinHttp
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct WinhttpCurrentUserIeProxyConfig
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public bool AutoDetect;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string AutoConfigUrl;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string Proxy;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string ProxyBypass;

    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("winhttp.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser(ref WinhttpCurrentUserIeProxyConfig pProxyConfig);

    public static string GetProxyForUrl(string reqUrl)
    {
        var config = new WinhttpCurrentUserIeProxyConfig();

        WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser(ref config);

        // System.Console.WriteLine("Proxy: {0}", config.Proxy); // eg. 104.129.192.32:443
        // System.Console.WriteLine("AutoConfigUrl: {0}", config.AutoConfigUrl); // http://xxxxx/nam.filt.pac
        // System.Console.WriteLine("AutoDetect: {0}", config.AutoDetect); // True
        // System.Console.WriteLine("ProxyBypass: {0}", config.ProxyBypass); // *.microsoft.com;*.corp.com;*.dev.microsoft.com;*.ms.com;*.local;<local>

        var w = System.Net.WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
        var url = new System.Uri(reqUrl);
        if (w.IsBypassed(url)) return "DIRECT";
        return w.GetProxy(url).ToString();
    }
}
"@

if ($reqUrl.length -eq 0) {
    echo "Missing argument"
    echo "getSystemProxyForUrl.ps1 -- will determine the proxy to be used for the given url"
    echo "Example:"
    echo "    powershell .\getSystemProxyForUrl.ps1 http://microsoft.com"
    echo "Outputs proxy url to standard out"
    echo "or if no proxy is required, outputs the word DIRECT"
    exit
}

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp  

([WinHttp]::GetProxyForUrl($reqUrl))
```

You can then run it from a command prompt or a batch file like so:

```
powershell .\getSystemProxyForUrl.ps1 http://microsoft.com"
```

If http://microsoft.com requires a proxy, it will be displayed in "standard out", otherwise it prints the word "DIRECT"

### From C#:

Note that, the section in @" "@ is all C# code, so someone who wants to do this from C#, just extract that code and pass the url to WinHttp.GetProxyForUrl()

### From NodeJS:

Use module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-system-proxy-for-url

Install:

```
$ npm i -S get-system-proxy-for-url
$ yarn add get-system-proxy-for-url
```

Example code:

```
var url = require('url');
var getSystemProxyForUrl = require('get-system-proxy-for-url');

getSystemProxyForUrl("http://google.com")
.then(function(proxy) {
    if (proxy === "DIRECT") {
        console.log("proxy not required");
    } else {
        var endpoint = url.parse(proxy);
        console.log(endpoint.href);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below URL in chrome and you will be able to see your Proxy settings

```
chrome://net-internals/#proxy
```

Answer (score 1):

```
netsh winhttp show proxy
```

-also works perfect on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Open regedit.exe and head over to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`
If a Proxy is enabled, you will find the address under `ProxyServer`

Answer (score -1):

```
netsh diag show ieproxy
```

run from command line, lets you know what proxy server you're using

Comment: The result of that is --> The following command was not found: show ieproxy

Comment: on my win10 laptop I get:
The following command was not found: diag show ieproxy